# WCF CustomBinding for CustomTextMessageEncoder using HTTPS

Tags: wcf, https, wcf-extensions

I am working on a WCF REST-type service that will accept text/xml type documents via a POST over HTTPS (ASP.NET 4.0 on IIS). Can someone help me with the web.config?  I'm testing with the sample code for the CustomTextMessageEncoder to parse the document.  I'm getting an error:
"Manual addressing is not supported with message level security. Configure the binding ('CustomBinding', 'http://tempuri.org/') to use transport security or to not do manual addressing."

Unfortunately, if I turn off ManualAddressing, I get a different error.  I'm not sure how to turn on TransportSecurity since it's a custom binding.

The main portions of the web.config for what I"m doing are:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyApp.MyApp" behaviorConfiguration="MyAppBehavior" >
        <endpoint address="https://myURL/MyApp/" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="newBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webEndpoint"  contract="MyApp.IMyApp" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://myURL/MyApp/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="https://myURL/MyApp/" />
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyAppBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="True" httpsGetUrl="https://myURL/MyApp/MyApp.svc/"  />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"  />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webEndpoint" >
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="customTextMessageEncoding" type="Microsoft.Samples.CustomTextMessageEncoder.CustomTextMessageEncodingElement, CustomTextMessageEncoder" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="newBinding" >
          <security authenticationMode="AnonymousForCertificate" />
          <customTextMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10">
          </customTextMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport manualAddressing="true" requireClientCertificate="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```